# ios UIView initWithCoder loads too fast

Tags: ios

inside of `initWithConder` `self.superview` will always return `(null)` for me.

How does one get *around* this?

***Thanks***

Comment: If this is being loaded from a nib file, you can use "-awakeFromNib"  The superview is defined by then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will *always* be the case because you can't add a view to a superview until it's initialized.

If you need to take an action based on its relationship with its superview, look at `- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview` and `- (void)didMoveToSuperview`.